# How to authenticate against a specific Organization?

Tags: stormpath, express-stormpath

I'm trying to build a multi-tenant application using Stormpath. The stack being used is Angular + Express. I'm using the 'Directory-per-Organization' strategy to organize my multi-tenant accounts. My Login form has a 'Organization ID' form field for user to specify the organization’s nameKey.

Is there a specific format in which this field needs to be passed to the stormpath-express backend? Stormpath-Angular SDK has no mention of this. Assuming there is no specific format,  I tried adding a preLoginHandler on the stormpath-express side to retrieve the org Id form field mentioned above and set a ***{accountStore : {nameKey : myOrgNameKey }}*** on the request body.  This however does not authenticate against the specified organization. Instead, it tries to match against all the organizations mapped to the application. I tested this my typing in invalid random strings for Org ID field.

As an aside, Stormpath’s site (api.stormpath.com/login) too does not seem to authenticate against the specified tenant Key. As long as the username and password credentials are fine, I can type in any string in the tenant field and it seems to log me in fine.

I want the username-password credentials to be checked only against the specified organization key and not against all the organizations mapped to the application. How do I go about this ?

Comment: Hey there, I work at Stormpath, and we're currently working on multi-tenancy support for express-stormpath. You can follow the open github issue here to be notified as we progress: https://github.com/stormpath/express-stormpath/issues/292

Comment: Until that issue is closed, you can use ID Site for multi-tenancy (https://docs.stormpath.com/rest/product-guide/latest/idsite.html#using-id-site-for-multi-tenancy). This will let you specify the organization's name key.

Comment: If you have any questions about this, feel free to reach out to us at support@stormpath.com